# How to connect from your iOS app to a backend server? how to read, modify and fetch data to backend server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, server, fetch, backend

I am new in developing iOS applications. I like to learn communication between my app and a specific back-end server(which is written in ruby). I would like to learn how to read, fetch and modify data on the back-end server? I do not have any idea where I should start? I am very welcome if you could refer me to any online resource/tutorial for this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create an API in ruby. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/surviving-apis-with-rails.

After that, when you are sure that your API is working correctly, you can write a service for HTTP communication. You can do it by yourself, but in my opinion, a much better option would be using the third party for that. I prefer using AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Heroku](https://heroku.com). First you can create your API and make some tests then implement to your server.